# Dynamic query builder stack too deep for Arel query Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I am looking for a way to construct a big dynamic query in Rails and applying an update to the given ActiveRecord relationship:

For example:

```rb
my_big_set = Set.new(big_array)
to_update_relationship = my_big_set.reduce(none) do |query, values_to_check|
                            where('condition = ? and condition_two = ?', values_to_check[:first], values_to_check[:two]).or(query)
                         end
    
to_update_relationship.update_all(field_to_update: true)
```

It works well when `to_update_relationship` is not too big. But if it gets bigger then the `reduce` output triggers a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` error when it constructs the Arel query.

Is there a clever way to workaround it? (other than splitting the input or increasing the ruby system stack size).

Thanks

PS: using rails 6 and ruby 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my solution finally is:

```
my_big_set = Set.new(big_array)
subquery = '(condition = ? and condition_two = ?)'
query = Array.new(my_big_set, subquery).join(' OR ')
query_values = my_big_set.map do |values_to_check|
   [values_to_check[:first], values_to_check[:two]]
end.flatten

where(query, *query_values).update_all(field_to_update: true)
```

that way, we construct:

1. the SQL query
2. the values to pass to `where()`
3. we still use active record `where()` in order to be protected from injection etc...

And this fixes the limit!

Answer (score 1):

you could use aggregate functions (for instance, postgresql `STRING_AGG` or mysql `GROUP_CONCAT`) to collect pairs of [condition, condition_two] then check those pairs `IN` your require conditions.

assume that you use postgresql, and conditions is something like `[{first: 1, two: 2}, {}, ...]`

```rb
pair_conditions = conditions.map {|pair| pair.values.join(",")} # ["1,2", ...]
Solution.group(:id, :condition, :condition_two)
.having("STRING_AGG(condition::TEXT || ',' || condition_two::TEXT, '') 
         IN (?)", pair_conditions)
```

the above query will `group` (condition, condition_two) and concat them to strings with format "condition,condition_two" so they be able to compare with pre-defined conditions on `having` clause.